# AJP connection fails

Tags: apache, centos7, tomcat9, openjdk-11

I have  two CentOS 7. On one I have Open JDK 11 & Tomcat 9.0.43. The AJP connection setting is like below

```
    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
           secretRequired="false" 
           address="::1"
           port="8009"
           connectionTimeout="10000"
           keepAliveTimeout="10000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Added host entry in tomcat server.xml like below

```
<Host name="ptm" appbase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                 directory="logs"  prefix="resumesite_log." suffix=".txt"
                 pattern="common"/> 
        <Context path="/myapp" docBase="/pathtowebapps/webapps/ptm" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
```

Firewall is disabled on both servers.

Proxy configuration is like below on apache 2.4

```
ProxyPass "/myapp" "ajp://<tomcatIP>:8009/myapp"
ProxyPassReverse "/myapp" "http://<tomcatIP>:8080/myapp"
```

I am able to connect to port 8080 via telnet but on port 8009 I am getting **Connection refused**.

Tomcat is listening on 8009, checked that with `lsof -i -P -n`

```
java       747     root   43u  IPv6 465743      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
java       747     root   49u  IPv6 465747      0t0  TCP [::1]:8009 (LISTEN)
java       747     root   62u  IPv6 466199      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8005 (LISTEN)
```

`java -version`

```
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.10+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

All ports are open from both machines.

Thanks for your help and support in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. Change the address to 0.0.0.0. That will do the trick.

**address="0.0.0.0"**

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
           secretRequired="false" 
           address="0.0.0.0"
           port="8009"
           connectionTimeout="10000"
           keepAliveTimeout="10000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```